# How do I find where bash functions are defined?

Tags: bash, reflection

I'm using an unfamiliar Linux system, and it has a command `use_python`. `type` reports that it's a function:

```
$ type use_python
use_python is a function
[... snipped source]
```

How do I find which file that function was defined in? Is it possible? I've had a look a the system's default bashrc, but it includes many other files.

Comment: Normally if they are set in `.bashrc` together with "is a function" you get the definition itself. But this is not happening here, so I don't really know. Have you tried grepping in all `~/.bash*` files?

Comment: Yes, use `find` and `grep` ...

Comment: @fedorqui I have the definition, I want to know which file contains that definition. I'll try grep (although I'll have to run it over all of /etc)

Comment: You can for example check if other users also have them. If not, check your `~/.*bash*` files. Otherwise, check `/etc` and so on.

Comment: Note that if you're just looking for the source of bash functions, `set` will show the soruce of all bash functions currently defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start your shell with `bash -x`. In all the `+`-prefix output that follows, you should be able to pick out a line that looks like `+ . some_file` (with one or more plus signs) that most closely precedes the definition of `use_python`, in which case `some_file` should be the file you want.

You may need to try `bash -lx` if `use_python` is only defined in a login shell.

Comment: There's not much else you can do. `bash` simply doesn't keep track of what was sourced where.